# How to convert CRAM file with 10x data in three fastq files

Tags: sam, fastq, format-conversion, cram

[10x Genomics](https://support.10xgenomics.com/single-cell-gene-expression/software/pipelines/latest/using/fastq-input) data are stored in three FASTQ files, besides the standard R1 and R2 reads, there is also a I1 file with some metadata. Sometimes however they are shipped in a single bam/cram file (e.g. the data from the Darwin Tree of Life). How can I convert the BAM or CRAM files to FASTQ?

-- edit --

Apparently, the I3 file is not 10x specific thing. It is an index generated when demultiplexing any Illumina data. See [this question](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/5178/what-is-the-index-fastq-file-sample-i-fastq-gz-generated-when-demultiplexing) for a nice explanation.

Comment: Isn't I1 the index read not unique to 10x data? But normally demultiplexing Illumina data with `bcl2fastq` does not generate these reads with default arguments

Comment: @Chris_Rands (after a bit of googling) you are right. I just not aware of its existence before I run into [this question on the tDToL GitHub](https://github.com/darwintreeoflife/darwintreeoflife.data/issues/2#event-4859159249). And then I thought I might as well put it here so it's easier to google it.

Answer (score 1):

All can be done with [samtools](http://www.htslib.org/). This is how [the Darwin Tree of Life folks convert it](https://github.com/darwintreeoflife/darwintreeoflife.data/issues/2#event-4859159249):

```
samtools fastq -@4 -i \
  -1 ${sample}_S${tag}_L%03s_R1_001.fastq.gz \
  -2 ${sample}_S${tag}_L%03s_R2_001.fastq.gz \
  --i1 ${sample}_S${tag}_L%03s_I1_001.fastq.gz \
  --index-format i8 ${lane}.cram
```

Comment: I don't know if that solution will work with 10xGenomics files.  You have to recreate R2 out of the contents of tags; there will be no reads with the read2 binary flag set.

Comment: @swbarnes2 I just have seen this thread: https://github.com/darwintreeoflife/darwintreeoflife.data/issues/2#event-4859159249 and tried to make it more googlable (because I do think there will be quite a few people who will be downloading the tDToL data).

Comment: I saw that thread too.  I don't think it's right.  samtools fastq -2 will work fine for bams from many applications, but not 10XGenomics.

Comment: @kamil, can you post a couple of lines of the BAM file showing how tags for R1 and R2 appear in 10x data? I can probably quite easily add support for this in https://genozip.com/sam2fq.html

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use the 10x provided bamtofastq tool to preserve the indices properly: https://github.com/10XGenomics/bamtofastq